# "Worked it around" or "worked around it"?

Tags: phrases

I had a sentence like this in my manuscript:

> [describing some limitation] .... Some studies **worked it around** by
> combining the results of two models ...

in the sense that those studies made a [workaround](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/workaround) for the limitation. The native speaker changed the bold term to **"worked around it"**, but I am almost sure I know the original form (from the IT world, where workarounds are a very common topic :)), and also can find it on the Internet. But I can find his version too, I just like the original one better. Are both acceptable? The result is supposed to be in US English, if it makes a difference.

(Note that this paper is not in the IT area, but the statistical modelling methods in ecology).

Comment: You must explain what you want "worked it around" to mean...

Comment: @fev Thanks. It means that those studies made a [workaround](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/workaround) for the limitation.

Comment: You said that you "can find it on the Internet", but is the expression used by reputable sources with your intended meaning? If so, can you cite some of them? (I don't recall ever having seen or heard that expression with that meaning.)

Comment: To _work s.t around_ means to change it to suit context: _We had to work the latch around a bit to install the new door_. Whereas _to work around s.t._ means to find another way (called a _workaround_) to perform an activity while avoiding some difficulty, or physical object: _We had to work around the washing machine in the middle of the floor._

Comment: *work it around* is not idiomatic English for dealing with some limitation; it’s *work around it*.

Comment: They mean two different things.

Comment: Have you decided that since a *workaround* (a substitute solution) is correct, "worked it around" is the same thing? It's not.

Comment: I'm CVing because OP has provided no evidence that "work it around" has the intended meaning despite suggesting that it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Girdhari Lal](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-phrasal-verbs-of-work-and-their-meanings), a senior English teacher in Rajasthan writes eloquently on Quora:

> - **work around something**:
>
> to find a way of working that avoids a particular problem without
> actually solving the problem
>
> *The lack of test data is a problem, but we've found a way to work around that.*

Mignon Fogarty in her [Phrasal Verbs Dictionary](https://linguisticsgirl.com/phrasal-verb-dictionary-w/) adds that the multi word verb is inseparable (My copy of Collins' Phrasal Verbs does not list the verb, but I suspect her claim is correct):

> - **work around**
>
> overcome  [inseparable] [transitive]
>
> *You can work around your inexperience with training.*

....................

However, arguably 'work someone around' could be used to echo 'bring someone a/round [to one's way of thinking] and 'come around [to one's way of thinking]':

*He's dead set against the merger, but Jill will work him around'.*

A broadening, 'work something around' could be used to mean 'bring something to a desired state'.

But note that the meaning is quite different ('re-educate' / 'adjust') from that of the multi-word verb ('use a method that successfully sidesteps the problem').

....................

- **To work something around something else** means to make sure the different elements dovetail smoothly:

> - Being consistent [in applying for jobs] is going to take some
>   determination. You need to be able to have a schedule that you can
>   stick to. Make sure to work it around your other daily commitments

[[Charlotte Rogers; University of Bath](https://engineering-jobs.theiet.org/article/the-importance-of-consistency-in-job-seeking)]

It is probably best seen as a [transitive verb] + [preposition phrase] structure.

Comment: For completeness, I'll append '**work around to [NP]/[ing-clause]**', meaning 'eventually get round to ...'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am not interested in the other meanings; only the one I mentioned, i.e. to [make something work despite the problem, without completely solving it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/workaround). Does it mean that in that context, only "work around something" is possible, but not the "work something around"?

Comment: I'm not saying it's _not_ used as a separable MWV (with that meaning), but I've seen no licensing of such usage in a reference book. I've never come across 'work X around' for 'work around X' (but then I'm British).

Comment: I am interested in the first meaning, so that is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You *work around* a problem, just as you *walk around* an obstacle.** The problem or the obstacle is still there, but you have got round it and on to you where you want to be.

At issue is the noun which is the object, and what it is the object of.

- Work around the problem

  The *problem* is a prepositional object, that which is worked around. The actual object of *work* is not stated. Generally the object of *work* is whatever you were actually working on — an algorithm, putting up a fence, wiring a light, whatever. The problem remains: an input variable is still out of expected range but you coded to cope with that; the fence needed to go over a manhole so you moved a fence post; the length of cable was too short so you put a joint in somewhere.
- Work the problem around

  The problem itself receives the work, and the problem is changed [which is what *around* indicates] to be something else. It's unidiomatic, particularly when what you actually mean is "work around the problem," and I can't come up with an example.